Can't get SM-900 to be accessible with fastboot on Linux
I'm using Debian GNU/Linux trixie (well, the Devuan equivalent to be exact), and am working on a Samsung SM-P900 Galaxy Note 12.2 Pro tablet.  As part of possibly flashing it, I need to make sure the bootloader is unlocked.
I have adb and fastboot installed. What I see is:
# adb devices
List of devices attached
5200b47af69a4247    device

# fastboot devices

so, visible with adb, not with fastboot. I found this question:
Fastboot connection problem
which said I can't see the device at the same time with both adb and fastboot, and that I should reboot it like so:
adb reboot bootloader

but when I do that - it reboots as usual, and I still see it only with adb.
I also tried the following:

Booted into recovery mode (using Power + Center-bottom button + Volume Up)
Chose "reboot to bootloader"

... that also resulted in a regular boot (showing my homescreen and apps), and device was still invisible with fastboot.
What can I do to get my tablet to be fastboot-visible (so I can flash it)?

Please keep in mind that bootloader unlocking works different for each device model/manufacturer. The Samsung devices I had work this way: Bootloader unlocking happens automatically if you have enabled OEM unlock in developer settings. If you then flash a new firmware with Odin/Heimdall and reboot the device, it recognizes that a firmware installed is not signed by Samsung and shows a dialog if you want erase all use data and unlock bootloader. If you have a custom ROM for your device this should be mentioned in the install guide.

@Robert: I don't actually have OEM unlock in the developer settings...

Samsung devices don't have fastboot mode. btw that device is not bootloader locked

@alecxs: That sounds like an answer... make it one?

Due the age of that device it is very likely that it was shipped with unlocked bootloader (except for Verizon branding) that's why there is no OEM unlocking in Developer Options.
Samsung devices have replaced Fastboot mode with its own bootloader mode, often called Odin mode or Download mode. Whenever it comes to fastboot commands on a Samsung device, we can assume it is about fastbootd in userspace, which is part of the recovery mode (not Download mode) on recent ROMs. Samsung devices (with few exceptions on Mediatek SoC) don't have classic fastboot mode.
Another reason for missing OEM unlocking Toggle in Developer Options is Samsung additional RMM protection (does not apply here)
In your case it is sufficient to flash custom binary (such as TWRP*) from Odin3 or Heimdall in Download mode, no bootloader unlocking necessary at all.
*Note that stock ROM replaces custom recovery with stock recovery on each boot (refer to installation instructions)

I don't understand what "recoveries" are exactly, perhaps you could link to an explanation? Also, I have managed to boot into Odin/Download mode, I just need to figure out how to flash the LineageOS image, but that's beyond the scope of this question I guess.

See here for TWRP// It's basically a mini operating system you get into to flash ROMs, take backups, make file system changes etc// There are many kinds of recoveries available with different features but the most importaant point to note is to use the recovery specifically  made for your exact device model...flashing anything is a recipe for disaster @einpoklum

if you already have lineageos.zip for your device just follow the Installation Guide. if not, follow the installation instructions of the download site of your choice
